# How to use Optional Headers in Artifactory REST API?

Tags: artifactory

I'm able to search using

```
GET /api/search/prop?[p1=v1,v2][&p2=v3][&repos=x[,y]]
```

as per the documentation. But how to use optional headers to get extra information for the found artifacts?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the HTTP header `X-Result-Detail` to `properties`. Using a curl command it would look something like this

```
curl -uUSERNAME:PASSWORD --request GET \
  --url 'http://jfrog.local/artifactory/api/search/prop?build.number=1&repos=generic-prod' \
  --header 'X-Result-Detail: properties'
```

This will look in my repository called `generic-prod` for all artifacts that have `build.number = 1` as a property.

That would return with the results you're looking for

```
{
  "results" : [ {
    "properties" : {
      "build.name" : [ "docker-jenkins-build" ],
      "build.number" : [ "1" ],
      "build.timestamp" : [ "1556557591780" ]
    },
    "uri" : "http://jfrog.local:80/artifactory/api/storage/generic-prod/jenkins.zip"
  } ]
}
```

This lists the properties I have for my artifact.